# Android Room: cross-referencing more than once or with a count

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

In my app, I've got the concept of a `NutritionDate` and `FoodItems`.

```kotlin
@Entity
data class NutritionDateEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val epochDay: Long,
    val year: Int,
    val month: Int,
)
```

```kotlin
@Entity
data class FoodItemEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val createdAt: Long = Instant.now().toEpochMilli(), // guaranteed to be unique, ascending
    val forEpochDay: Long = 0L,
    val name: String = "",
    val fact: String = ""
)
```

I've also got a cross-reference table to track which `FoodItem`s are included in which `NutritionDate`s:

```kotlin
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["epochDay", "foodItemCreatedAt"])
data class NutritionDateAndFoodItemCrossRefEntity(
    val epochDay: Long,
    val foodItemCreatedAt: Long,
)
```

I came across the issue that I can't include a food item in the list multiple times (say I ate two burritos and wanted to add it twice).

I thought about adding a `count` property to the cross reference table, or trying to make some kind of lookup table for cross-reference + count, but the primary key for the cross-reference entries are composite. Maybe trying to add an auto-incrementing primary key to the cross reference entries to make them unique? Couldn't really find any good info on doing that either.

I'd like to do this in an idiomatic way if possible. Is there a good / standard way to do this with Room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of different strategies, I ended up getting it to work well with something relatively simple that I should have tried in the first place:

```kotlin
@Entity
data class NutritionDateEntity(
    @PrimaryKey 
    val epochDay: Long,
    val year: Int,
    val month: Int,
)
```

```kotlin
@Entity
data class FoodItemEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val createdAt: Long = Instant.now().toEpochMilli(), // guaranteed to be unique, ascending
    val forEpochDay: Long = 0L,
    val name: String = "",
    val fact: String = ""
)
```

```kotlin
@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = NutritionDateEntity::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("epochDay"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("epochDay"),
            onDelete = CASCADE,
            onUpdate = CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = FoodItemEntity::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("createdAt"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("createdAt"),
            onDelete = CASCADE,
            onUpdate = CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class FoodEntryEntity( // formerly CrossRef
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,
    val epochDay: Long,
    val createdAt: Long,
)
```

Instead of using a composite primary key for the cross reference table, I decided denote it as a "food entry" and give it an auto-incrementing `@PrimaryKey`. I can still use it in a `@Relation` annotation to create the following when I query `NutritionDates`:

```kotlin
data class NutritionDateWithFoodItems(
    @Embedded
    val nutritionDate: NutritionDateEntity,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "epochDay",
        entityColumn = "createdAt",
        associateBy = Junction(FoodEntryEntity::class)
    )
    val foodItems: List<FoodItemEntity>
)
```

Also necessary was an `upsert` implementation to prevent `@ForeignKey` delete cascades when calling an `@Insert(onConflictStrategy = REPLACE)` method (note the `REPLACE` is now `IGNORE`):

```kotlin
@Dao
interface FoodItemEntityDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(foodItemEntity: FoodItemEntity): Long

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun update(foodItemEntity: FoodItemEntity)

    @Transaction
    suspend fun upsert(foodItemEntity: FoodItemEntity) {
        val result = insert(foodItemEntity)
        if (result == -1L) update(foodItemEntity)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either way. However, you might prefer to add a quantity column to NutritionDateAndFoodItemCrossRefEntity. This is a little more efficient space wise and also slightly easier if trying to ascertain the quantity (no need for a POJO or separate function and a query that has GROUP BY clause, a count expression (The POJO (with a field/member/variable for the count) or separate function to get the count)).

> but the primary key for the cross-reference entries are composite.

You should know the values that make up the composite key, so this should not be an issue.

You may wish to consider adding an index for the second column of the composite key. You may also wish to add ForeignKey clauses to help ensure referential integrity (no orphans). As such perhaps consider:-

```
@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["epochDay","foodItemCreatedAt"],
    /* Room will issue warning if no index on foodItemCreatedAt */
    /* MUST NOT BE unique index */
    indices = [
        Index(value = ["foodItemCreatedAt"])
              ],
    /* Adding Foreign Key Definitions will enforce referential integrity */
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = NutritionDateEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["epochDay"],
            childColumns = ["epochDay"],
            /* Optional what to do if a parent is deleted/updated */
            /* CASCADE (the most commonly used option) propogates the action to the children */
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = FoodItemEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["createdAt"],
            childColumns = ["foodItemCreatedAt"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class NutritionDateAndFoodItemCrossRefEntity(
    val epochDay: Long,
    val foodItemCreatedAt: Long,
    val quantity: Long
)
```

You @Dao class could, as an example, be/include:-

```
@Dao
abstract class NutritionDao {

    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(nutritionDateEntity: NutritionDateEntity): Long
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(foodItemEntity: FoodItemEntity): Long
    /* IGNORE if conflict (duplicate) used for insertOrInCrement below*/
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(nutritionDateAndFoodItemCrossRefEntity: NutritionDateAndFoodItemCrossRefEntity): Long
    @Query("UPDATE nutritiondateandfooditemcrossrefentity SET quantity = quantity + :adjustment WHERE epochDay=:epochDay AND foodItemCreatedAt=:foodItemCreatedAt")
    abstract fun adjustNutritionAndFoodItemCrossRefEntity(adjustment: Long, epochDay: Long, foodItemCreatedAt: Long)

    /* Signature that uses the actual objects */
    fun insertOrIncrementNutritionFoodItemCrossRefEntity(nutritionDateEntity: NutritionDateEntity, foodItemEntity: FoodItemEntity) {
        if (insert(NutritionDateAndFoodItemCrossRefEntity(nutritionDateEntity.epochDay,foodItemEntity.createdAt,1)) < 1) {
            adjustNutritionAndFoodItemCrossRefEntity(1,nutritionDateEntity.epochDay,foodItemEntity.createdAt)
        }
    }

    /* Signature that uses the values */
    fun insertOrIncrementNutritionFoodItemCrossRefEntity(epochDay: Long, createdAt: Long) {
        if (insert(NutritionDateAndFoodItemCrossRefEntity(epochDay,createdAt,1)) < 1) {
            adjustNutritionAndFoodItemCrossRefEntity(1,epochDay,createdAt)
        }
    }
}
```

- Note that abstract class used instead of interface, this allows non-abstract functions with a body and hence the insertOrIncrement... functions

**Demo**

Considering the above and the other code you supplied then the following in an activity (run on the main thread for brevity/convenience) :-

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    nutritiondao = db.getNutritionDao()

    var f1crtd = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var f2crtd = f1crtd + 100
    var f3crtd = f2crtd + 100

    nutritiondao.insert(FoodItemEntity(forEpochDay = 1,name = "F1",fact = "Fact for F1",createdAt = f1crtd))
    nutritiondao.insert(FoodItemEntity(forEpochDay = 2,name = "F2", fact = "Fact for F2", createdAt = f2crtd))
    nutritiondao.insert(FoodItemEntity(forEpochDay = 3, name = "F3", fact = "Fact for F3", createdAt = f3crtd))

    nutritiondao.insert(NutritionDateEntity(10,2021,1))
    nutritiondao.insert(NutritionDateEntity(11,2021,1))

    nutritiondao.insertOrIncrementNutritionFoodItemCrossRefEntity(10,f1crtd)
    nutritiondao.insertOrIncrementNutritionFoodItemCrossRefEntity(10,f1crtd)
    nutritiondao.insertOrIncrementNutritionFoodItemCrossRefEntity(10,f2crtd)
    nutritiondao.insertOrIncrementNutritionFoodItemCrossRefEntity(10,f3crtd)
    nutritiondao.insertOrIncrementNutritionFoodItemCrossRefEntity(10,f3crtd)
    nutritiondao.insertOrIncrementNutritionFoodItemCrossRefEntity(10,f3crtd)

    /* Adjust example */
    nutritiondao.adjustNutritionAndFoodItemCrossRefEntity(-100,10,f2crtd)
```

- 3 FoodItemEntity's are added.

  - The primary keys being specified and stored.
- Then 2 NutritiondateEntity's.

  - The primary keys being specified and stored.
- The first FoodItem is added to the cross ref.
- The first FoodItem is added again (but not as the duplicate conflict is detected and thus the update increments the original, so the quantity is now 2)
- the second FoodItem is added to the cross ref (so quantity is 1)
- the third food item is added 3 times (so quantity ends up as 3)
- the second FoodItem is adjusted adding -100 so the quantity becomes -99.

The database after running the above, as per Android Studio's App Inspector (formerly Database Inspector) :-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My end goal is to use [this class](https://gist.github.com/carterhudson/237485f40a2433c0a851bdff4f88b577) with each food item being present in the list the same number of times the as the "count" on the xref. I'm not sure I see a way to do that with this implementation, other than manually querying and joining the data sets myself. I'm fine with an individual cross ref entry for each time the food item is "linked" to the `NutritionDate`, but I'm not sure how to use Room to retrieve that info without manual queries / joins.